# Mysql inserts resource #16 to DB table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I am having an issue here, in my code a user can add friends, but when the push the button to accept the request they get the confirmation, and their name is stored in the database, but the user they are accepting is stored as resource id #16. Also it inserts this 10 times into the data base. The request values are not being deleted from the requests table. What am I doing wrong thank you

```
<?php
include ('c://website/mysite/views/header.php');
require_once ('c://website/mysite/config/config.php');
include('c://website/mysite/config/connection.php');

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error()) ;
global $user_name,$page_owner,$username;

$user_name = trim(strip_tags($_SESSION["user_name"]));
    //This is the user who  logged into the system or logged in session

$page_owner = trim(strip_tags($_SESSION["user_name"])); 
    // This is the owner of the page viewed

$username = mysql_query("select * from request where friend ='".$_GET["username"]."'");
$user_id = mysql_query("select user_id from users where user_id = 'user_id'");

$check_request = mysql_query("select * from `request` 
        where `username` = '".$user_name."' 
            and `friend` = '".$username."' 
            or `friend` = '".$user_name."' 
            and `username` = '".$username."'")
    or die(mysql_error()) ;

if(mysql_num_rows($check_request) > 0); 
    //If already added as friend, friendship confirmed

mysql_query("delete from `request` 
        where `username` = '".$user_name."' 
        and `friend` = '".$username."'");

mysql_query("delete from `request` where `username` = '".$username."' and `friend` = '".$user_name."'");     
@mysql_query("insert into `friends` values('', '".$username."', '".$user_name."')");

@mysql_query("insert into `friends` values('', '".$user_name."', '".$username."')");

echo "friend_ship_confirmed";
```

Comment: $username = mysql_query("select * from request where friend ='".$_GET["username"]."'");

You should select his username instead of * here

Comment: i'll post it as an answer, you just need to accept it :)

Comment: Perfect thanks again I was going crazy trying to figure it out :)

Comment: No worries :) Resource # means there's many items being shown instead of 1. Always be careful using *, it's better to specify which fields you need ( it's also faster, since otherwise it's getting Everything from the database when you don't need it )

Comment: That makes perfect sense, no need to grab every field in the row for just the user name I'll keep that in mind

Comment: $username = mysql_query("select * from request where friend ='".$_GET["username"]."'");  -> sql inject danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select his **username** only instead of selecting everything (*)

```
$username = mysql_query("select username from request where friend ='".$_GET["username"]."'");
```

instead of

```
$username = mysql_query("select * from request where friend ='".$_GET["username"]."'");
```